# How to use customRender in a table cell with Antd and VueJS

Tags: vue.js, antd

I'm using antd in my app and I'm trying to do a customRender to show an image in a cell.

My columns array looks like this:

```
columns: [
        { title: 'Design',
          dataIndex: 'designImage.fileUrl',
          customRender () { // h will be injected
            return '<div id="foo">bar</div>'
          }
        },
]
```

So, as you might imagine, it turns out like this:

[image]

I also tried this way:

```
{ title: 'Design',
          dataIndex: 'designImage.fileUrl',
          customRender: (text, record, index) => {
            return {
              children: '<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff">'
            }
          }
        },
```

Unfortunately, that ended up like this:

[image]

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of the **scopedSlots** property within columns, and use it to define a scoped slot for the **customRender** property.

Here is an example:

```js
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Image",
    dataIndex: "image",
    key: "image",
    scopedSlots: { customRender: "image-column" },
  },
];
```

Now, in your template, you can use the **image-column** named slot, like this:

```html
<a-table :columns="columns" :data-source="tableData">
    <template slot="image-column" slot-scope="image">
        <img :src="image" /> <!-- Add your custom elements here -->
    </template>
</a-table>
```

And here is a component example:

```html
<template>
  <a-table :columns="columns" :data-source="tableData">
    <template slot="image-column" slot-scope="image">
      <img :src="image" />
    </template>
  </a-table>
</template>

<script>
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Image",
    dataIndex: "image",
    key: "image",
    scopedSlots: { customRender: "image-column" },
  },
];

const tableData = [
  {
    image: "https://picsum.photos/200",
  },
  {
    image: "https://picsum.photos/200",
  },
];

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      columns,
      tableData,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use antd's Table, customRender should return a vnode but not a string, so you can try it like this

```
columns: [
        { title: 'Design',
          dataIndex: 'designImage.fileUrl',
          customRender () { 
            return <div id="foo">bar</div>
          }
        }
]
```