# Antd customRender return raw html

Tags: html, vue.js, antdv

I need to generate html code in a `customRender` function of one column.

I **cannot** use `scopedSlots` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66820539/1039488), since the html code is part of e generic component, and other components pass their columns array as a parameter.

**BaseComponent.vue:**

```
<template>
    <a-table
        :columns="attrs.columns"
        :rowKey="record => record[attrs.recordId]"
        :dataSource="filteredTableData"
    >
    </a-table>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            attrs: {
                type: Object,
                required: true
            }
     :
</script>
```

**ContactComponent.vue:**

```
<template>
      :
    <base-component :attrs="attrs"/>
      :
</template>

<script>
    import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent';
    export default {
        components: {
            BaseComponent
        },

        data() {
            return {
                attrs: {
                    columns: [
                        title: 'Type',
                        dataIndex: 'type',
                        customRender: (val, record) => {
                            return '<div class="myClass">' + val + </div>';
                        },

                    ],
                    recordId: 'contactId'

                }
            }
        }
     :
</script>
```

**The problem:**
The following code:

```
customRender: (val, record) => {
    return '<div class="myClass">' + val + '</div>';
},
```

renders this:
[image]

Is there a way to force raw html rendering directly from the `customRender` function?

Comment: How do you call the customRender in template?

Comment: In template there is no code referring to specific columns since it is a generic code

Comment: why cannot you use slots?

Comment: The base component is generic, I don't want to add to it code of a specific parent-component. It is a possible solution (since it will not be rendered for other components that do not have this column), but do not follow a basic programming rule of maintaining the code as generic as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your code:

```
customRender: (val, record) => {
    return '<div class="myClass">' + val + '</div>';
},
```

In this way (if you have JSX support).

```
customRender: (data) => {
    return <div class="myClass"> {data.text} </div>;
},
```

If you dont have JSX support, you can return a Vnode. Like specified here: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#creating-vnodes (I didn't try this way).

Or you can try to add support for JSX: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#jsx-tsx

(My reply is late but may help others.)

==========

Edit:

Here, another exemple, to show you where this piece of code should be (only work with JSX support):

```
data: function () {
    return {
        dataSource: [],
        columns: [
            {
                title: 'Website',
                dataIndex: "cat_website",
                key: "cat_website",
                customRender: (data) => {
                    return <a href={'http://' + data.text} target='_blank'>{data.text}</a>;
                },
            },
            // other columns...
        ],
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try this code? It does not seems to be working.

Comment: Yes, that should work. I edited my post with another example (that I use in one of my project) that can may help you.

Comment: I don't think it should work, you are trying to return something which in neither string nor any acceptable javascript data type. Please test your code, and if it works add a code snippet to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I edited my post. I have support for JSX in my project. You can check here for more information: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#jsx-tsx